# Reported speech about something that is still in the future

Tags: future, indirect-speech, backshifting, future-in-past

> He said (in 2015), "Driverless cars will be common by 2020."

My understanding is that today (2024), we definitely backshift:

> He said driverless cars would be common by 2020.

---

But what about if the reported speech is about something that's still in the future?

> He said (in 2015), "Humans will have colonies on Mars by 2050."

Today (2024), which is acceptable: 1, 2, or both?

> 1. He said humans **would** have colonies on Mars by 2050.
> 2. He said humans **will** have colonies on Mars by 2050.

Answer (score 3):

From [Word Reference Forum](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/they-said-they-would-vs-they-said-they-will.2546873/), where Annadim asks the same question [minor tweaks, eg bolding, mine]:

> Which grammatical tense would you use in the following situation? You
> are reporting about a past meeting, where someone took a commitment to
> do something in the future – ***the future relative to the time when you
> are reporting***, not only relative to the time when the commitment was
> made.
>
> Would you write
>
> - "They said they would do xyz in the future"
>
> or
>
> - "They said they will do xyz in the future"?
>
> This does not seem to me to be a case of 'future in the past' so I
> would go with the second option, but please correct me if otherwise.
>                                               
> – Annadim [2012]

......

> Both can be used. *It is not decisive* [necessary] *that the future action is still
> in the future from now* [the time of reporting]. I would say the normal way of saying it is
> with 'would'. The direct speech 'will' is converted to 'would' under a
> simple principle of tense agreement with the main verb 'said'. If in
> doubt, use tense agreement; it will always (or almost always?) be
> right. The past tense form on the subordinate verb †doesn't imply any
> past time, or any limitation of time.
>
> [We had a thread on this a little while back, where someone came up
> with many good real examples of not using tense agreement. The opinion
> I formed then, faced with this evidence, was that tense agreement is
> used when you're mainly concerned with their action of saying. When
> that saying is just background, and all you care about is what they
> said, non-agreement ('will' rather than 'would') is likely. So, to
> exaggerate the different meanings, a bit:
>
> - "They said they would tell the employees of their decision." [That's what they said. Maybe they will and maybe they won't.] [†Maybe they
>   already have done, EA.]
> - "They said they will tell the employees of their decision." [A firmer commitment]
>
> The present tense 'will' is more marked, more unusual, than the past
> tense 'would', which as I said before is the normal way of saying it.
>                                        – entangledbank

Comment: Yeah, would because it is the past tense of will in reported speech (standard usage). That's the reason. In news writing etc. it's definitely would.